# How to add a class selector name to another existing class selector in css?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

```
.flavor {
  text-align: left; 
  width: 75%;
}
```

Now I want  to add another class selector "dessert" to this "flavor" class selector. How to add it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add next selector after comma.

```
.flavor, .dessert {
   text-align: left; 
   width: 75%; 
}
```